# Conditional for a nested object in an array in Send Grid dynamic template

Tags: handlebars.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

```
 "events": [
            { 
                "event": {
                    "level": "violation"
                },
                "type": "temperature"
            },
            {
                "event": {
                    "level": "violation"
                },
                "type": "battery"
            }
        ]
```

I need to write a conditional to show one color if there's a violation and another if there's a warning. Not sure how to write this in SendGrid's dynamic template, cause it's either working if there is only type or only level in the conditional, but not both

I tried writing this, but it's not working. Can anyone help me out

```
   {{#each data.events}}
       {{#if this.event.level}}
           {{#equals this.event.level "violation"}}
              {{#equals type "battery"}}
                 <p style="color:#F00; font-size:30px;">&#8226;</p>
              {{/equals}}
       {{else}}{{equals this.event.level "warning"}}
                  <p style="color:#FF0; font-size:30px;">&#8226;</p>
               {{/equals}}
       {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: Should it be `{{#equals this.type "battery"}}`?

Comment: Apologies for being this late, but it worked either way.
Thanks for replying. We have changed the whole thing now, so it's working fine.